# AWS, Beanstalk, Autoscaling EC2 configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just started hosting a legacy classic ASP app on AWS Beanstalk. When I created the environment, I used RDP to remote into the Windows machine and configure IIS with classic ASP, server includes etc.

Funny thing (or not) is that sometimes the Autoscaler adds an instance (scales up) and then removes an instance (scales down). If it removes my originally configured server, I loose the changes I made via RDP and my website goes down.

Is there a way to specify how the scaled EC2 instance is configured?

Many thanks,

Comment: Haven't you setup an image to boot an instance from? When using autoscale you can't rely upon a specific installation, they WILL change as the oldest installations are removed first.
There is also a way to update code from another server after an instance was booted. And there are API available for various languages with which you can control almost everything you can see in the administration interface.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have an AMI that I would prefer to use, just not sure how I connect this to the autoscaler from the AWS console.

Comment: Do you already have a Launch Configuration and Autoscaling Group set?

Comment: Looking at this now ... I do have a launch config and Autoscaling group. Maybe I just create a new launch config from the preferred AMI and attach to the existing autoscaling group?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments that set me onto this. I used the AWS console for all of this and solved my issue.

- From the EC2 instance page, create an AMI of your configured EC2 instance
- Under EC2 > Auto Scaling > Launch Configuration create a new launch configuration using your AMI. You will see a previously created configuration created by Beanstalk but you are creating your own.
- Under EC2 > Auto Scaling > Auto Scaling Groups you will see a group already created by Beanstalk. Edit this Auto Scaling group and specify your new launch configuration.

Hope this helps,